# Switching 2 fragments within one activity - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, onclicklistener

I'm trying to replace one fragment with another following a button click (onClick) event.  I'm new to fragments so if I'm going about this the wrong way please let me know.

At run time a frame layout (container) is loaded.  A fragment is then added to it dynamically.  This works fine.  If I add in the setOnClickListener I get a NullPointerException.  Here's the Java:

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

FrameLayout container;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    //setContentView(R.layout.welcome_fragment);
    container = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainContainer);



    // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
    // the fragment_container FrameLayout
    if (findViewById(R.id.mainContainer) != null) {

        // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
        // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
        // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
        addWelcomeFragment();

    }


  //NPE at the below line  
  Button submitUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitUser);
  submitUser.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

      @Override
      public void onClick(View view){
      addExpedFragment();
      }  
  });
}
```

Through researching fragments I'm using static class within the WelcomeActivity class to load the fragments.  They are here:

```
    public static class WelcomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public static Fragment newInstance(){
        Fragment wFrag = new WelcomeFragment();
        return wFrag;

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_fragment, null);


        return v;
    }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
public static class ExpedFragment extends Fragment {

    public static Fragment secondInstance(){
        Fragment eFrag = new ExpedFragment();
        return eFrag;


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exped_fragment, null);


        return v;
    }
}
```

And the methods to invoke these are also with WelcomeActivity here:

```
    private void addWelcomeFragment(){
    Fragment welcome = WelcomeFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction fTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


    fTrans.add(R.id.mainContainer, welcome);
    fTrans.addToBackStack(null);
    fTrans.commit();
}


private void addExpedFragment(){
    Fragment exped = ExpedFragment.secondInstance();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContainer, exped).commit();
}
```

I have a feeling that the problem is to do with trying to find the button view id "submitUser" from the first fragment.  My xmls look like this.

The first empty FrameLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

  <FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The first fragment loaded in at runtime:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:id="@+id/welcome_fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
tools:context=".WelcomeActivity" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/welcome"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/welcome1"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/userName"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/welcome"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/welcome"
android:layout_below="@+id/welcome"
android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/userHint"
android:inputType="textPersonName" >

<requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
android:id="@+id/submitUser"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/userName"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/userName"
android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:text="@string/Done" />
<FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The second fragment to replace the first with the onClick event:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:id="@+id/exped_fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
tools:context=".WelcomeActivity" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/expedText"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/exped"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">

</TextView>

<FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

IF I forget loading the first fragment at runtime and setContentView(first fragment) there is no NullPointerException but the two fragments overlay each other when the button is pressed rather than replacing.

So my question is, how do I reference the active fragment to properly set the OnClickListener and avoid the NullPointerException?

```
Button submitUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitUser);
```

gives the NPE

Comment: What line gives the NPE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

```
Button submitUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitUser);
```

The `submitUser` is located in your `WelcomeFragment's layout` not in your `Activity's layout` that is why it is null.

**solution:**

Instead of initializing it in your `activity class` you need to initialize it within your `Welcome fragment` view.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_fragment, null);
    Button submitUser = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.submitUser);
    submitUser.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

       @Override
       public void onClick(View view){
        addExpedFragment();
       }  
   });

    return v;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
 private void addExpedFragment(){
    Fragment exped = ExpedFragment.secondInstance();
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContainer, exped).commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply.  The call to addExpedFragment(); is now giving an error "cannot make a static reference to a non-static method".  Should I just take the static classes out of the main activity and have them as separate classes?

Comment: @OliverBurdekin just put the method in your WelcomeFragment class

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin : No, the method shouldn't be in the WelcomeFragment. Fragments shouldn't know about each other. Instead the OP should define a Callbacks interface which is then implemented by the Activity. When the Button is clicked the listener should then call a method in the interface / Activity.

Comment: I tried putting the addExpedFragment() method in there too.  The leads to the same error message but this time for getSupportFragmentManager().

Comment: @Squonk I'd be interested to know  why fragments shouldn't know about each other.  I'll read up on interfaces.  It's been a while since I've used java.

Comment: @OliverBurdekin : From the third paragraph of Design Philosophy of this link https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html **"You should design each fragment as a modular and reusable activity component. That is, because each fragment defines its own layout and its own behavior with its own lifecycle callbacks, you can include one fragment in multiple activities, so you should design for reuse and avoid directly manipulating one fragment from another fragment."**